# Code generator as a gradle plugin or dependency

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, dsl, gradle-plugin

I've written a code generator https://github.com/vjuge/cdmdsl which uses gradle's buildSrc  to generate some kotlin DSL code, from a financial model library named 'CDM' https://regnosys.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-snapshot

It's using java's reflection capacity to generate the DSL dynamically (the model change quite often, new types are introduced, properties are changed/removed, etc.)

It is working fine, and thus we can include this DSL to manipulate the model easily, from inside any java-based applications.

The drawback today is that I need to regularly build and deploy versions of my DSL in order to follow CDM releases. This is a bit annoying and not sustainable.

I wonder if there is any way to make my project able to build 'on-the-fly', as a dependency:

1. An application would implement two dependencies : this DSL + CDM lib
2. The application would set the wanted CDM dependency version
3. The DSL would be used like a gradle plugin to generate the code based on the corresponding cdm version at application's build time

Hopefully my description is clear enough!

Answer (score 1):

Check Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP), which is the newest tool/API to write compiler plugins or processors. With it, you can write a plugin that parses the CDM library and generates the DSL, making it available right away to the client app. This would happen during the client project build phase, producing a local and unique DSL based on the CDM version.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bv-VyGM3HCY

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html